# Objective-C UIRefreshControl not workng

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to implement a `UIRefreshControl` onto my `UITableView` without having to have a TableViewController and setting the '**Refresh**' to Enabled.

So far I've globally declared the following in my **ViewController.h** file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIRefreshControl *refreshView;
-(void)refreshTableView;
```

And have added the following code to my `viewDidLoad` in the **ViewController.m** file:

```
self.refreshView = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshView.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Pull To Refresh"];
[self.refreshView addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshMyTableView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshView];
```

Finally, I have this method to go with it, in my **ViewController.m** file:

```
-(void)refreshTableView {
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.refreshView endRefreshing];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any light on this matter will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do using this code ?

```
self.refreshView = self.refreshView;
```

Change that and try with:

```
[yourTableView addSubview:self.refreshView];
```

Comment: Awesome. This allowed me to see the "pull to refresh" UI but now when I do pull to refresh it, it crashes with the following error:

"-[FFViewController refreshMyTableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Any ideas? I'd definitely appreciate it.

Comment: You should add to your FFViewController the method you set in the UIRefreshControl, so - (void) refreshMyTableView { //Do something }

Comment: @Vik My apologies..ViewController.m is the FFViewController.m.

In other words, I already have that method there. As stated above in the code.

Comment: Then try to do 

[self.refreshView addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshMyTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

(I added : after the selector name)

And write the method signature like this 

- (void)refreshMyTableView:(id)sender { //Do something }

See if this changes something

Comment: It's quite strange otherwise that the selector is unrecognized

Comment: You're a genius! :D That worked perfectly!
Thanks so much Vik.

Comment: @VIk , What are the chances that you're free to help some more? I'm working on a project with the deadline being tomorrow..but theres one last thing that's just not working. We can be in the same Chat, if possible. I would greatly, HUGEly appreciate it! :)

Comment: There are not really many chances since I'm working right now, too ^_^ but if it's something easy, I can help you. What kind of chat are you using?

Comment: Hehe, I see. Any chat that is best to you. Skype, Facebook, even gmail is good.

Comment: The last part is driving me crazy. I've spent hours on it with hardly any advancements.. Of course I'm sure it's nothing you can't handle..considering how quickly you handled the UIRefreshController.. :)

Comment: @YaserSleiman: sorry, I didn't see your chat. Sorry for that :) Anyway thanks for adding comment. Remember `unrecognized selector sent to instance` will raise when you try to call a method which is not present in the class. So whenever you get this error check the method name and argument list

Comment: @MidhunMP Hehe, no worries :) All worked out well. Yes I'll definitely have to remember that one for next time. Thanks again :)

Comment: @MidhunMP I sent you an email from the About.me page. I hope you recieved it :)